# Egghead Redux tutorial: Lesson 19

Tags: javascript, redux

I am getting this error and I'm not sure why. I am assuming I missed a step. I've gone over the lesson a few times but cannot figure out what I did wrong.

```
"error"
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at TodoApp.render (xuwuwoqaso.js:157:23)
```

The code is below. I think it is referring to the .map function under `TodoApp` with `visibleTodos.map(todo => ...)`

As I understand it, `store.getState()` is being passed in and then mapped over with `visibleTodos`and creating the error. Is that right?

```
const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id:action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state;
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        completed: !state.completed
      };

    default:
      return state
  }
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        todo(undefined, action)
      ];

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(t => todo(t, action))  

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const visbilityFilter = (
  state = 'SHOW_ALL',
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const { combineReducers } = Redux
const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
  visbilityFilter
});

const { createStore } = Redux;
const store = createStore(todoApp);
const { Component } = React;

const FilterLink = ({
  filter,
  children
}) => {
  return (
    <a href='#' 
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        store.dispatch({ 
          type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER', 
          filter
         }); 
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};

const getVisibleTodos = (
  todos,
  filter
) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos;
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(
        t => t.completed
      );
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(
        t => !t.completed
      );
  }
}

let nextTodoId = 0

class TodoApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(
      this.props.todos,
      this.props.visibilityFilter
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref ={node => {
          this.input = node;
        }} />

        <button onClick = {() => {
          store.dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TODO', 
            text: this.input.value, 
            id: nextTodoId++
          });
          this.input.value = ''
        }}>
          Add Todo
        </button>
        <ul>
          {visibleTodos.map(todo =>
            <li key={todo.id} 
                onClick={() => {
                  store.dispatch({
                    type:'TOGGLE_TODO',
                    id:todo.id
                  });
                }}
                style = {{
                  textDecoration: 
                    todo.completed ?
                      'line-through' :
                        'none'
                }}>
              {todo.text}
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
        <p>
          Show:
          {' '}
          <FilterLink filter='SHOW_ALL'>All</FilterLink>
          {' '}
          <FilterLink filter='SHOW_ACTIVE'>Active</FilterLink>
          {' '}
          <FilterLink filter='SHOW_COMPLETED'>Completed</FilterLink>
          {' '}
        </p>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <TodoApp 
      {...store.getState()} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
};

store.subscribe(render);

render()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `class TodoApp extends Component {` isn't `@connect`ed to your redux store, which is what gives your components store data as props. Then you call

```
const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(
  this.props.todos,
  this.props.visibilityFilter
);
```

But since you haven't connected your component to the store, props will be empty, and you're calling `getVisibleTodos` with empty arguments.

You need to [`connect()` (or use decorator @connect)](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) your `TodoApp` component, which is fully covered in the tutorial videos. You may have skipped over it accidentally.

Comment: doesn't `store.subscribe(render)` connect it?

Comment: Whoops, I missed that line!

Answer (score 0):

It was a spelling mistake with `VisibilityFilter` woops!